# How to fill sublist which has another join

Tags: c#, linq

I want to fill my sublist through linq joins. How to achieve this?  Below commented out code where I could not figure out.

```
var model = (from personel in db.Personels
     where personel.ID == id
     from contact in personel.ContactTypes 

     join contactType in db.ContactTypes on contact.ContactTypeId equals contactType.ID

     select new PersonelWithContactListDto
     {
         PersonelName = personel.PersonelName,
         PersonelLastname = personel.PersonelLastname,
         PersonelPrivateNo = personel.PersonelPrivateNo,
         // here how to select my sublist. If I leverage
         // let = dbobjects.DefaultIfEmpty() then I am no 
         // longer able to specify contactType from another table.
         //Contact = contacts.Select(x => new ContactListDto
         //{
         //    Value = x.Value,
         //    ContactType = contactType.Value,
         //    ID = x.ID
         //}).ToList()
     }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here is my dto class.

```
public class PersonelWithContactListDto
{
    public string PersonelName { get; set; }

    public string PersonelLastname { get; set; }

    public int PersonelPrivateNo { get; set; }

    public IList<ContactListDto> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my domain classes with relational maps.

It's Personel Class

```
public class Personel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PersonelName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PersonelSurname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public int PersonelPrivateNo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

It's Contact class which every person may have multiple

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ContactTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContactTypeId")]
    public virtual ContactType ContactType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersonelId")]
    public virtual Personel Personel { get; set; }

    public int PersonelId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is every contact's type information.

```
public class ContactType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone put me in a right direction?

Comment: More information needed about the other classes...Contacts & Personal classes

Comment: @SudeepReddy I've added domain classes aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the join in the wrong place. Try this:

```
var model = (from person in personel
                where person.ID == id
                select new PersonelWithContactListDto {
                    PersonelName = person.PersonelName,
                    PersonelLastname = person.PersonelSurname,
                    PersonelPrivateNo = person.PersonelPrivateNo,
                    Contacts = (from contact
                                in person.Contacts
                                join contactType in contactTypes
                                on contact.ContactTypeId equals contactType.ID
                                select new ContactListDto {
                                    Value = contact.Value,
                                    ContactType = contactType.Value,
                                    ID = contact.ID
                                }).ToList()
                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, let me try this out.

Comment: @user3055125 no problem. If it works, please mark this as the accepted answer by clicking the green tick to the left :)

Comment: just changed "on contact.contactTypeId equals contactType.ID" and it has worked like a charm thanks.

Comment: Oops - my bad. I've updated the answer so it is accurate :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have an `id`, and you want the one and only `Personel` with this `id`, together with all his `Contacts`. You don't want all properties of the `Personel` with this `id`, but only `PersonelName`, `PersonelLastname` and `PersonelPrivateNo`.

From every `Contact` of the fetched `Personel` you also don't want all properties, but only properties `Value`, `ContactType` and `id`

Your `Personel` class already has a property that holds the `Contacts` that you want. So why do a join? Use the ICollection and your framework (looks like entity framework to me) will know that a join is needed:

```
var personWithHisContacts = myDbContext.Personels
    .Where(person => person.Id == id)
    .Select(person => new
    {
        // select only the Person properties you plan to use:
        Name = person.PersonelName,
        LastName = person.PersonelLastName,
        PrivateNo = person.PersonelPrivateNo,

        // I want all contacts of this Person:
        Contacts = person.Contacts
            .Select(contact => new
            {
                // again: select only the properties you plan to use:
                Id = contact.Id,
                Value = contact.Value,
                ContactTypeValue = contact.ContactType.Value,
            })
            .ToList(),
    });
```

I think that using the `ICollection` of `Contacts` is a neat way that clearly shows that every `Personel` has zero or more `Contacts`. It also hides that internally this is done using two separate tables with a foreign key.

Did you notice that the `Select` part takes up most of the query?

Your framework will know that using the ICollection requires a join. If you really think that specifying the join explicitly do something like:

```
var personWithHisContacts = myDbContext.Personels // from all Persons
    .Where(person => person.Id == id)             // take the one with id
    .GroupJoin(myDbContext.Contacts               // GroupJoin with all Contacts
    person => person.Id,             // from each person take Id
    contact => contact.PersonelId,   // from each contact take PersonelId
    (person, contacts) => new        // when they match, make a new object
    {                                // containing only the properties you plan to use
        Name = person.PersonelName,
        LastName = person.PersonelLastName,
        PrivateNo = person.PersonelPrivateNo,

        // I want all contacts of this Person:
        Contacts = contacts.Select(contact => new
            {
                // again: select only the properties you plan to use:
                Id = contact.Id,
                Value = contact.Value,
                ContactTypeValue = contact.ContactType.Value,
            })
            .ToList(),
    });
```

The `Select` part is not really changed. The use of the ICollection is changed by a GroupJoin. I can't see why anyone would prefer that above the ICollection method, but is you really want to...

Comment: So do you say this approach is more reliable and performs a lot better? With personel's contact information am I also able to get his contact's type aswell? If so, I might prefer this approach of course.

Comment: The performed SQL statement will be similar, see your sql profiler. The improvement is that it is better readable for others (and thus less errors after changes and easier to change), more reusable: because you hide that internally it is two tables in a database with a foreign key. Therefore, your code works for every collection of persons with their contacts, even if not in a database, but just in unit-test memory

Answer (score -1):

See if this helps :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DB db = new DB();
            int id = 123;

            var model = (from personel in db.Personels
                         where personel.ID == id
                         from contact in db.ContactTypes

                         join contactType in db.ContactTypes on contact.ID equals contactType.ID

                         select new PersonelWithContactListDto
                         {
                             PersonelName = personel.PersonelName,
                             PersonelLastname = personel.PersonelSurname,
                             PersonelPrivateNo = personel.PersonelPrivateNo,
                             // here how to select my sublist. If I leverage
                             // let = dbobjects.DefaultIfEmpty() then I am no 
                             // longer able to specify contactType from another table.                             
                             Contacts = personel.Contacts.Select(x => new Contact() {
                                 Value = x.Value,
                                 ID = x.ID
                             }).ToList()
                         }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class DB
    {
        public List<Personel> Personels { get; set; }
        public List<ContactType> ContactTypes { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonelWithContactListDto
    {
        public string PersonelName { get; set; }

        public string PersonelLastname { get; set; }

        public int PersonelPrivateNo { get; set; }

        public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }


    public class Personel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        public string PersonelName { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        public string PersonelSurname { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        //[Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public int PersonelPrivateNo { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int ContactTypeId { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("ContactTypeId")]
        public ContactType ContactType { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("PersonelId")]
        public virtual Personel Personel { get; set; }

        public int PersonelId { get; set; }
    }


    public class ContactType
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This is not correct - the OP is trying to get the `ContactType.Value` joined into the `ContactListDto.Value` field. Your solution does not achieve this.

Comment: So where do we set Contact Type here on this approach? There seems no contact type here.